# passing RDD into an utility function

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark

In order to make code more clean, I put some tasks/functions in the main code into an utility class/function, then pass the entire RDD to the function, like:

```
val myResultRDD = MyUtiltity.processData(myRDD1, myRDD2, myRDD3).saveAsTextFile("output", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

then the code becomes very slow compare with keeping everything in the main code. I am wondering if I have 10 executors, does the job copy myRDD1, myRDD2, and myRDD3 to each executor? So I have 10 myRDD1, 10 myRDD2, and 10 myRDD3 in the memories?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't wastefully `cache()` or `collect()` RDDs inside your utility function, then what you have here **should not** affect performance.

Applying a sequence of transformation (e.g., map, fold, reduce, etc.) to any number of RDDs and combining them into a new RDD (say, though joins) does not execute anything until you either `collect` or `persist` the RDD. Therefore, adding your sequence of transformations in a function or having them scattered in your "main" should not affect performance.

Comment: So there is only 1 myRDD1, 1 myRDD2, and 1 myRDD3 even though I have 10 executors?

Comment: The executors map to partitions and not directly to RDDs. If you have 10 executors it means you can be operating on 10 partitions at the same time. These 10 partitions can be from a single RDD or from 10 smaller RDDs. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If RDD1 has 10 partition, but RDD2 has 1 partition, what would happen?

Comment: And if I .cogroup RDD1 and RDD2 while RDD1 has 10 partitions and RDD2 has only one partition, will the job be distributed to 10 executors?

Comment: If you only have 10 executors, that's the max you can execute in parallel. If you have an RDD of 100 partitions it means that you will process it 10 partitions at a time. Now, if you have 2 RDDs of 10 and 1 paritions, assuming you process them in parallel, then it's up to the internal DAG scheduler to decide if it will first run the jobs for RDD1 and then for RDD2 or any other configuration.